# Xamarin.UWP publish x64 and ARM64

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uwp

Surface Pro X uses ARM processor.
So far, I have been publishing UWP app using x64 architecture only.
I have created ARM64 and managed to build release version successfully.
However, when I choose Publish -> Create app package, I don't see the option to select Release/ARM64 in the drop down menu.
Also, when I select x64 and ARM64, an error message says "Selecting mixed solution configuration is not allowed when generating app bundles".
Any assistance greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have selected Release mode before generating App Bundle. If you have different configuration(**Debug** x64 & **Release** ARM etc.,), it will show this error "*Selecting mixed solution configuration is not allowed when generating app bundles*". Ensure it is release configuration in all your selections(**Release** x64 & **Release** ARM).

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this by changing the the .sln and .csproj files to use arm & arm64 instead of ARM & ARM64.  Windows 10 development machine is, somehow, case-sensitive.

Comment: ,Glad to hear that you have solved your issue now, please remember to mark your reply as answer, thanks.